# Can you join 2 columns with inner join from 2 tables?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to find matching x- and y-coordinates from two tables.  The x- and y-coordinates of one table should only be returned if both coordinates match
Example of the two tables:

### **tblBomb**

| yCo | xCo |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |

### **tblFarm**

| yCo | xCo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 0 | 4 |

Here is an example of the SQL statement I have used:

```
FROM tblFarmOne
INNER JOIN tblBombTwo
ON ((tblFarmOne.yCo = tblBombTwo.yCo) AND (tblFarmOne.xCo = tblBombTwo.xCo));
```

When I run this query it doesn't give me an error message, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Since your sql query uses tblFarmOne and tblBombTwo and the actual table-names are different, it seems that you are selecting these tables more than once, maybe thats the reason. It works with your sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/56a39/2/0

Comment: I would suggest you include some actual sample data to illustrate what is not working; your parentheses are also redundant and it would make your query easier to read (and debug) if you used meaningful table aliases.

Comment: A SQL statement usually starts with `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me -
I notice you use `tblFarmOne` and `tblBombTwo`
Could you possibly have those two tables, too, in addition to `tblBomb` and `tblFarm` only that they contain different data?

```
WITH
-- your input data
tblbomb (yco,xco) AS (
            SELECT 2,1 
)
,
tblfarm (yco,xco) AS (
            SELECT 1,0 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 0,4 
)
SELECT
  *
FROM tblbomb
JOIN tblfarm
  ON tblbomb.yco=tblfarm.yco
 AND tblbomb.xco=tblfarm.xco
;
 yco | xco | yco | xco 
-----+-----+-----+-----
   2 |   1 |   2 |   1
```